# Class is not applied to Material UI button component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply a class (redirectButton) to material UI button , but it is not getting applied.
here is my html

```html
      {(isDataAdapterAdmin && !dataSources?.length) &&
            <Button className={classes.redirectButton} onClick={() => history.push('/settings_systems/dataSources')} >
              {i18n._(buttonText)}
            </Button>
          }

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  redirectButton:{
    'display': 'flex',
    'justify-content': 'center',
    'margin-right': '400px'
  }

}))
```

In output, the parent div is something like this

```
 <div class>
```

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem. At a minimum, please include the full code of the component that uses `useStyles` (so that we can see exactly how `classes` is set). By "full code" I mean the simplest possible version of your component that still reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to apply the style to the `root` element you need to override classes:

[Documentation here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes)

```
classes={{ root: classes.redirectButton }}
// insted of 
className={...}
```

Comment: The documentation you linked to says "When the `className` property **isn't enough**, and you need to access **deeper elements** ...", but if all you care about is the root element, then the `className` property **is** enough. `className={classes.redirectButton}` is equivalent to `classes={{root: classes.redirectButton}}`. [className](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L308) and [classes.root](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L297) are always applied to the same element.

Comment: classes={{ root: classes.redirectButton }} Tried this, still no luck

Comment: className is not always aplied to the root element, and in order to pass the class to the right part of the component you need to read the API of that component , in this case : [Button api](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css)

Comment: @CevaComic Yes, className is always applied to the root element (in every case where `root` is one of the valid classes for the `classes` prop).

Comment: My bad in this case, sorry :). Anyway I solved this kind of problems with override the classes in the api (including root).